# How to change default value size parameter of the terms aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

By default, the terms aggregation returns the top ten terms with the most documents.
How to change default value of the size parameter of terms aggregation?

Elasticsearch 7.12.0

Kibana 7.12.0

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "default value"?

Comment: "default value" of size that is by default 10. @Val

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy one to find in the official documentation but you can change the default number of buckets in a `terms` aggregation using the [`size` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size):

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "genre",
        "size": 20                 <--- change this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
But I can not change this value when I use create new rule in Kibana, when I define new rule that rule type "Threshold" was selected, by default size is 10:{
"aggregations": {
"eventActionGroup": {
"terms": {
"order": {
"_count": "desc"
},
"size": 10,
....

Comment: Ok it wasn't clear this was in the context of Kibana alerting rules. There are many different "threshold" rule types, which one is it exactly?

Comment: rules->Create new rule->Threshold
Aggregate query results to detect when number of matches exceeds threshold. @Val

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: Elasticsearch 7.12.0 and Kibana 7.12.0